# grpc: does grpc hide local connections?

Tags: python-3.x, tcp, protocol-buffers, grpc

I'm playing with `python` examples that come with `grpc` in examples\python* directory, helloworld for instance. I noticed interesting thing: when I start the server (on localhost port 50051), and then the client -- I don't see a TCP connection created (with `ss -tnep`), however I do see the packets exchange with tcpdump.

On the other hand, if I simply `telnet localhost 50051`, ss command does show connection. Does `grpc` somehow hides connection when done over the localhost, perhaps some sort of optimization? Or is this a Linux specific feature, which is explicitly enabled by grpc?

I'd appreciate some comments that would help to understand this better, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nope. There's no hiding going on. I can see the connection just fine on my machine:

```
(venv) rbellevi@rbell:~/Dev/tmp/grpc/examples/python/helloworld$ ss -tnep | grep 50051
ESTAB      0      0                                       [::1]:38404                      [::1]:50051 users:(("python3",pid=694984,fd=9)) uid:615173 ino:95459744 sk:c9436c cgroup:/user.slice/user-615173.slice/session-c2.scope <->                       
ESTAB      0      0                                       [::1]:50051                      [::1]:38404 users:(("python3",pid=693220,fd=8)) uid:615173 ino:95454843 sk:c94487 cgroup:/user.slice/user-615173.slice/session-c2.scope <->
```

Comment: Very strange. I'm following instructions from https://www.grpc.io/docs/languages/python/quickstart/